# Angular 4 loading screen: add item to html and hide it after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a loading screen that takes about 15-30 seconds depending on the data that's loaded. It loads about 50 items and displays on the page:

`Loading item x`

It uses an observable/subscription for each data call made to the DB.  Upon receiving the data, the subscription fires off and adds it to an HTML string:

```
sync() {
    this.syncStatus = "Starting sync"
    this.syncService.sync().subscribe((status: string) => {
        this.syncStatus += "<div>" + status + '</div>';
    }, (error: string) => {
        console.log(error);
    }, () => {
        this.Redirect();
    });
}
```

`<div class="description">
   <span [innerHTML]="syncStatus"></span>
</div>`

As of now, it simply shows the list and it cuts off the list display because it gets so long (again, 50+ items, sometimes hundreds). I was wondering, how do I show each individual item to the page for 5s then hide it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of objects with the insertion time of the item, then filter the array based on this property.

```
sync() {
    this.syncStatus = [{ msg: 'Starting Sync', time: Date.now() }];
    this.syncService.sync().subscribe((status: string) => {
        this.syncStatus.unshift(status);
        this.removeOldEntries();
    }, (error: string) => {
        console.log(error);
    }, () => {
        this.Redirect();
    });
}
```

Then filter old entries:

```
removeOldEntries() {
   this.syncStatus = this.syncStatus.filter((status) => status.time < Date.now() - 300000); // 5 minutes
}
```

Comment: Hi, I changed the unshift line to `this.syncStatus.unshift({msg: status, time: Date.now()});` to make it add to the array.  Nothing shows now. Any thoughts?  Great idea, btw @TheUnreal

Comment: Don't use innerHTML, use `ngFor` to iterate the array instead.

Answer (score 0):

> It would be great if you take advantage of components in Angular

[Stack Blitz, Source Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4-loading-screen-add-item-to-html-and-hide-it-after-5-s)

> Explanation

1. You don't need date creation to check when a data was received
2. You don't need filtering through hordes of data
3. If you use Angular component approach, life would be easier, Each component will be responsible for removing itself

> Main Component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  data = [
    "Hello 0"
  ];

  count = 1;

  ngOnInit() {
    // Think of this as your subscription to backend
    setInterval(() => {
      if (!this.data) {
        this.data = []
      }

      this.data.push("Hello " + this.count ++);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

> Main Component.html

```
<div class="description">
   <div *ngFor="let datum of data; let i = index">
     <hello [ref]="data" [index]="i">{{datum}}</hello>
   </div>
</div>
```

> Hello.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() ref;
  @Input() index: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    // This code will remove this component, upon 
    // the timeout you specify
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.ref.splice(this.index, 1);
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```